# Empty groups in Kanban view of Odoo10

Tags: kanban, odoo-10

Is it possible to show groups (columns) without any items in Kanban view of Odoo10?

I [found an article](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/odoo-grouping-kanban-view-empty.html) how to do that in Odoo8, but the way that is described there doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In odoo 10 `group_by_default` is replaced by `group_expand` and it takes list of all your stages.
for e.g your columns are `stage` and you want to show all empty stages.

```
@api.model
def _read_group_stage_ids(self,stages,domain,order):
    stage_ids = self.env['stage.stage'].search([])
    return stage_ids

stage = fields.Many2one('stage.stage', group_expand='_read_group_stage_ids')
```

Comment: What if my stage is a Selection field? Or should I always use a Many2one relation for a stage?

Comment: Since ATM there seems to be no doc on group_expand, take a look at odoo/models.py and search for _read_group_fill_results. This is where group_expand gets interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

"*_read_group_stage_ids* " method return a list of stages so in your case try to pass all selection fields object in list form to *group_expand* method .